# Why my program plays the sound first and then moves the frame with label?

Tags: tkinter

I am working on app for shadow boxing using tkinter. I want to cover screen with label and then I want program to play sound. Most of the time it plays the sound first and cover it afterwards or doesnt cover it at all. I even tried to divide it into two different functions but it didnt work either.

Here is the problem part of code:

¨

```
display = Tk()
jedna_zvuk = mixer.Sound("Zvuky/jedna.wav") #1
dva_zvuk = mixer.Sound("Zvuky/dve.wav") #2
tri_zvuk = mixer.Sound("Zvuky/tri.wav") #3
ctyri_zvuk = mixer.Sound("Zvuky/ctyri.wav") #4
pet_zvuk = mixer.Sound("Zvuky/pet.wav") #5
sest_zvuk = mixer.Sound("Zvuky/sest.wav") #6

cisla = ["1","2","3","4","5","6"]
seznamy = [["1","2"],["2","3"],["2","5"]]
akce = ["2","1","3"]
casMeziUdery = 500
casMeziKomb = 1500

    def Start():
        frameNaZakryti.place(x=0, y=0) 
        labelNaZakryti.pack()
        akce.sort()
        ran = random.choice(seznamy)
        a = all(x in akce for x in ran)
        if a == True:
            for q in range(len(ran)):
                inndex = cisla.index(ran[q])
                Zvuky[inndex].play() 
                if q != len(ran):
                    display.after(casMeziUdery)
            zvukTlacitka.play()
            display.after(casMeziKomb)  
        Start()
```

Comment: Your code has many missing parts, better provide a [mre].

Comment: Got it. Is this enough?

Comment: Of course not. Can you execute *your posted code* successfully?  Obviously there are still missing parts and indentation issue.  Also should `Start()` be outside of the definition of `Start()`? And where is the *moving frame* code? I just see a frame which is always *placed* at (0, 0).